# How to NOT open Visual Studio Code from the command line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I see a lot of posts asking how to open VScode from the command line; I have the opposite problem!

When a type a file name from the CMD terminal, VSCode is launched with the file contents...why is that? I don't want that to happen!  Any ideas on how to stop this from happening?

Comment: Can you give example of input you type into CMD.

Comment: Check here https://thisdavej.com/right-click-on-windows-folder-and-open-with-visual-studio-code/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check your environment variables and find path for VScode, then delete it

Also maybe in your file properties VScode is set to default opening app , so it open files by default
For example (In my case Intellij IDEA) it looks something like this:
[image]

this mean you should go to properties and change "opens with" options
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hints; they both helped on solving the problem.

The one particular file that I wanted to execute and NOT open with vscode is a bash script file with extension " .sh ".

I checked the file manager and it is not associated with vscode; instead, it says "SH Source File".

Then, I followed the link to thisdavej and after seeing the proposed registry entries, I went ahead and looked into my own registry...found that the .sh extension had an "OpenWithProgids/VSCode.sh", deleting that solved my problem.  Now, when I type the name of the shell script, it actually executes.

Thanks.